# Jitsi-meet video conference connection failed automatically after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs, jitsi-meet

I have installed Jitsi-meet at my own server as per documentation and its working fine.

**Problem:** When I create video conferencing and share URL to join othres they can join successfully but they disconnected after 10 seconds with below errors in console.

> [conference.js] :  CONFERENCE FAILED: conference.setup_failed
>   Error: ICE fail
>       at i.peerconnection.oniceconnectionstatechange (lib-jitsi-meet.min.js?v=3081:2)
>       at RTCPeerConnection.peerconnection.oniceconnectionstatechange (lib-jitsi-meet.min.js?v=3081:2)

http://prntscr.com/lj53ir

**My server URL:** https://3.16.95.59/

Has anybody face this before or have experience of it.

I have search and tried many solution but no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/2805#issuecomment-381170045

Comment: a couple of likely causes to this, especially with the failed pings, your server just isn't up to scratch (what are the specs) and so is dropping packets left and right, or you haven't got https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html working correctly so the server doesn't know to keep the connection alive.